# What are the camper upgrades?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

The penguin OK Garage appears to upgrade my camper as Tom Nook used to upgrade my home. They performed the first upgrade (expansion of the main floor) and then left me to pay off the 10,000 bells on loan. What are the possible upgrades and how much do they cost? Do the loans have any affect on gameplay apart from giving more room to decorate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Main floor expansion: 10,000 bells
2. Second floor addition: 30,000 bells
3. Second floor expansion: 50,000 bells
4. Main floor width: 100,000 bells

Upgrades appear completely cosmetic so far.

Comment: 4. Main floor expansion: 100,000 bells